# Android Selector Drawable with VectorDrawables srcCompat

Tags: android, vector, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

I'm facing a problem with the new backward compatibility with VectorDrawables.
In the Support Library 23.2 was a new feature for backward compatibility with Android VectorDrawables indroduced.

I have an ImageView which is a SelectorDrawable assigned to. This Drawable holds several VectorDrawables so I thought I should use app:srcCompat for compatibility. But it does not work on my Galaxy S2 with android 4.1.2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_gps_fixed_24dp"android:state_activated="true" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_gps_not_fixed_24dp" android:state_activated="true" android:state_selected="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_gps_not_fixed_24dp" android:state_activated="false" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_gps_off_24dp" android:state_activated="false" android:state_selected="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_gps_not_fixed_24dp"></item>
</selector>
```

All drawables are vector xml files.

When using this SelectorDrawable with srcCompat I get this error:

```
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_gps_fixed_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0201c1
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1951)
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:672)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
                                                                           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881).xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0201c1
```

using android:src is even worse.

If I use one of the vector drawables with app:srcCompat all works fine. So I guess it's a problem with the SelectorDrawable and compatibility.

Has anyone had the same problem and found a solution or is it currently not possible to use VectorDrawables in SelectorDrawables prior to Android 5?

The Quick Facts:

- Compile Target API 23
- Support Libraray 23.3.0
- vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
- Gradle 2.0

Comment: Support for loading vector drawables from resources was removed in version 23.3 - https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/iTDmFiGrVne

Comment: But: "Using app:srcCompat and setImageResource() continues to work" so app:srcCompat should still work in 23.3. or not?

Comment: Yes using app:srcCompat still works so you can set one VectorDrawable to an ImageView.  However loading the drawables in an xml state list no longer works unfortunately

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Some things have changed since I asked this question, so I will answer it myself.

With Support Library 23.4.0 the support for VectorDrawables from Ressources was reenabled: [Android Support Library 23.4.0 available now](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/B7QhFkWZ6YX)

You can find more information on that in this cast from the Google I/O 2016:
[What's new in the support library - Google I/O 2016](https://youtu.be/w45y_w4skKs?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8jQTUYvIfqA9lMvSGQWtte&t=1194)

You need to add this to every Activity where you want to use VectorDrawables on devices below Android 5.0 (Codename Lollipop, API level 21):

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

So you can now use VectorDrawables in DrawableContainers but it can still cause some issues as mentioned in the sources above so use it with caution.

I did not reenable this feature in my app so far but I will change a lot of my icons to VectorDrawables with my next major release and will then dive deeper into this topic.

Comment: Also, the following bug report might be of help: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210745&pageId=109201119303080409719

Comment: "You need to add this to every Activity where you want to use VectorDrawables on devices below Android 5" is not true, we need that even for android 15

Comment: @stallianz Android 5 equals API level 21. Do not confuse release versions with API versions.

Comment: where do you use `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` ?I've used it but I am now getting the error `XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: invalid drawable tag vector`

Comment: @F43nd1r Well at least call it android 5.0. Android 5 is ambiguous.

Comment: @hqzxzwb I was clarifying what the op wrote in his answer. I also just edited the answer to include that clarification.

Answer (score 65):

As @Jahnold mentioned in the comment to question, support for loading vector drawable from an xml state xml list was removed in 23.3.

However, I found several approaches that can help.

**1. Using Tint**

The approach is suitable if the drawables from selected state list difference only by colors.

First, create only one vector drawable with tint and white `fillColor`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tintMode="multiply"
    android:tint="@color/button_tint">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M2.01 21L23 12 2.01 3 2 10l15 2-15 2z"/>

    <path
        android:pathData="M0 0h24v24H0z"/>

</vector>
```

Second, create color state list `button_tint.xml` placed in `res/color`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#555555" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="#6699dd"/>
</selector>
```

Don't forget add follow lines to `build.gradle` or the approach will not work on old Android versions.

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

**2. Hardcode creating `StateListDrawable`**

The approach is suitable if you use for the state list vector drawables which difference not only a color but also by a figure so you need create several different xml files. Then you can create `StateListDrawable` programmatically as shown in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36762775/939193).

Comment: I spend an hour to find that the `button_tint.xml` file should be placed under `/res/color` folder. So, don't forget it.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be defining the tint and tint mode in the drawable itself. This limits the drawables reusability. If the designer decides to change the color, or have the same icon but in different colors, you'd need to duplicate the drawable instead of just tinting it using a style etc

Comment: @Ghristopher Perry In this case you can use the second approach.

Comment: This works! Make sure to use android:tint, and not app:tint.

Answer (score 7):

After watching **What's new in the support library - Google I/O 2016** I noticed one useful method in the `AppCompatResources` class. This is `AppCompatResources#getColorStateList(Context context, int resId)`. With a help of this method I've implemented selector with vector drawables. Here is my color selector file `icon_selector`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/red_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/red_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/red"/>
</selector>
```

And there is java method that returns tinted drawable:

```
private Drawable getTintedDrawable(@DrawableRes int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId, getTheme());
    } else {
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);
    }
    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable.mutate(), AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this, R.color.selector_nav_bar_item_ico));
    return drawable;
}
```

You can use it like shown below

```
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(getTintedDrawable(R.drawable.ic_vector_image));
```

Answer (score 4):

Working fine with below changes.

```
static {
 AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

Added in Application class.
app build.gradle inside defaultConfig

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Comment: In my case I had useSupportLibrary set and yet my app on api 16 crushed because I set drawable state list with svg in it. So, it seems, I have to use both variants

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this workaround to make the color change based on state:
Set a normal, white VectorDrawable, and have the tint have the color selector.

This was tested to work even on emulator with Android API 16, and it works even if you set "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true" in gradle, of course.

Example: first view is enabled, and the second is disabled:

[image]

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        disabledSendMessageButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

**res/layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true" android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:minWidth="?attr/actionBarSize" android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" android:padding="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24" app:tint="@color/color_selector"
        tools:targetApi="m" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/disabledSendMessageButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" android:minWidth="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" android:padding="8dp" android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24" app:tint="@color/color_selector" tools:targetApi="m" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**res/color/color_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

**res/drawable/ic_baseline_send_24.xml**

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M2.01,21L23,12 2.01,3 2,10l15,2 -15,2z"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `animated-selector`

example

https://github.com/alexjlockwood/adp-delightful-details

https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html

create `animated-vector` file with this tool

https://shapeshifter.design/