# How to create a custom drawable with diagonal gradient with round edges?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gradient

Am trying to make a custom drawable using xml, like the attached image [image]

Below are two approach i have done,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="30dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:endColor="#000"
    android:startColor="#ffff"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

By doing like this i can get the effect right, but the colors seems to be merged, I want two colors without any merge effect, then i tried like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/white">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/size_30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="35"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/textColorGreyExtraLight" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

This approach actually messed up the UI, also i have compromise on the rounded edges,

So i there any way i can draw this effect using XML?

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

**FYI** The width and height of drawable will vary, so the diagonal should be always left bottom edge to right top edge.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason for you to define it like that? Otherwise why not to use a Vector image or just a PNG?

Comment: Yea. One reason is, the application sometimes changes whole theme, including the colors, @Eselfar

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke android:color="#0a0909"
    android:width="2dp"/>

<corners android:radius="20dp"/>

<gradient android:angle="45"
    android:type="linear"
    android:startColor="#d61a1a"
    android:endColor="#19f269"
    android:useLevel="false"/>

<size android:height="250dp"
    android:width="250dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image: you will get output like this]

Comment: See Raghav, I totally appreciate your effort, in case you haven't read my question properly, i want to have a diagonal line, not the merged effect, Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

While you asked for an XML based solution, I was intrigued to build a custom `Drawable` to solve your issue. It basically just draws two shapes using custom paths and a border around them. If you add setters for the colors or make them constructor parameters, you'll get the flexibility you need for when the applications theme changes. Feel free to ignore this if XML is the way to go for you, I had fun building it. :)

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of custom drawable]

```
public class CustomDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final int mBorderWidth;
    private final int mCornerRadius;

    private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mTopLeftShapePaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mBottomRightShapePaint = new Paint();

    private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

    private final Path mTopLeftShapePath = new Path();
    private final Path mBottomRightShapePath = new Path();

    public CustomDrawable() {
        mBorderWidth = 8;
        mCornerRadius = 64;

        mTopLeftShapePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00a2e8"));
        mTopLeftShapePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mTopLeftShapePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mBottomRightShapePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#3f48cc"));
        mBottomRightShapePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mBottomRightShapePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#3f48cc"));
        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);
        mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);

        mBorderRect.set(bounds);
        mBorderRect.inset(mBorderWidth / 2, mBorderWidth / 2);

        calculatePaths();
    }

    private void calculatePaths() {
        // Calculate position of the four corners
        RectF topLeftCorner = new RectF(mBorderRect.left, mBorderRect.top, mBorderRect.left + 2 * mCornerRadius, mBorderRect.top + 2 * mCornerRadius);
        RectF topRightCorner = new RectF(mBorderRect.right - 2 * mCornerRadius, mBorderRect.top, mBorderRect.right, mBorderRect.top + 2 * mCornerRadius);
        RectF bottomLeftCorner = new RectF(mBorderRect.left, mBorderRect.bottom - 2 * mCornerRadius, mBorderRect.left + 2 * mCornerRadius, mBorderRect.bottom);
        RectF bottomRightCorner = new RectF(mBorderRect.right - 2 * mCornerRadius, mBorderRect.bottom - 2 * mCornerRadius, mBorderRect.right, mBorderRect.bottom);

        // Calculate position of intersections of diagonal line and top-right / bottom-left corner
        PointF topRightCornerIntersection = calculateCircleCoordinate(topRightCorner.centerX(), topRightCorner.centerY(), 315);
        PointF bottomLeftCornerIntersection = calculateCircleCoordinate(bottomLeftCorner.centerX(), bottomLeftCorner.centerY(), 135);

        // Build top left shape
        mTopLeftShapePath.reset();
        mTopLeftShapePath.moveTo(topLeftCorner.left, topLeftCorner.centerY());
        mTopLeftShapePath.lineTo(bottomLeftCorner.left, bottomLeftCorner.centerY());
        mTopLeftShapePath.arcTo(bottomLeftCorner, -180, -45, false);
        mTopLeftShapePath.lineTo(topRightCornerIntersection.x, topRightCornerIntersection.y);
        mTopLeftShapePath.arcTo(topRightCorner, -45, -45, false);
        mTopLeftShapePath.lineTo(topLeftCorner.centerX(), topLeftCorner.top);
        mTopLeftShapePath.arcTo(topLeftCorner, -90, -90, false);

        // Build bottom right shape
        mBottomRightShapePath.reset();
        mBottomRightShapePath.moveTo(bottomLeftCorner.centerX(), bottomLeftCorner.bottom);
        mBottomRightShapePath.lineTo(bottomRightCorner.centerX(), bottomRightCorner.bottom);
        mBottomRightShapePath.arcTo(bottomRightCorner, 90, -90, false);
        mBottomRightShapePath.lineTo(topRightCorner.right, topRightCorner.centerY());
        mBottomRightShapePath.arcTo(topRightCorner, 0, -45, false);
        mBottomRightShapePath.lineTo(bottomLeftCornerIntersection.x, bottomLeftCornerIntersection.y);
        mBottomRightShapePath.arcTo(bottomLeftCorner, 135, -45, false);
    }

    private PointF calculateCircleCoordinate(float centerX, float centerY, double angdeg) {
        double angle = Math.toRadians(angdeg);
        double x = centerX + mCornerRadius * Math.cos(angle);
        double y = centerY + mCornerRadius * Math.sin(angle);
        return new PointF((float) x, (float) y);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(mTopLeftShapePath, mTopLeftShapePaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mBottomRightShapePath, mBottomRightShapePaint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mBorderRect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mBorderPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: this quick draft doesn't cover edge-cases, e.g. a corner radius that is too large for the given view bounds.

Comment: Looks promising!! One doubt how can I attache this to my layout?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't access a custom `Drawable` in a layout resource XML, you'd have to set it programmatically using `ImageView#setImageDrawable(new CustomDrawable())`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, simplest way is to draw background in `SVG` format and directly use it as background, or, if you want to change colors programmatically, you can convert `SVG` to vector drawable (for example with [this](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) tool) and than use as background. For your example `VectorDrawable` (`two_colored_roundrect.xml`) can be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="550dp"
        android:height="390dp"
        android:viewportWidth="550"
        android:viewportHeight="390">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#00bfbf"
        android:strokeColor="#003f7f"
        android:strokeWidth="5"
        android:pathData="M1.50016,66.028801l0,0c0,-35.411501 28.03274,-64.118481
62.611443,-64.118481l28.463097,0l0,0l136.615303,0l256.152985,0c16.605011,0
32.529999,6.75751 44.274994,18.780581c11.744995,12.0231 18.338013,28.3319
18.338013,45.3379l0,160.295204l0,0l0,96.177002l0,0c0,35.410004
-28.03302,64.11499
-62.613007,64.11499l-256.152985,0l-136.615303,0l-28.463097,0c-34.578703,0
-62.611443,-28.704987 -62.611443,-64.11499l0,0l0,-96.177002l0,0l0,-160.295204z" />
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#003f7f"
        android:strokeWidth="5"
        android:pathData="M 19.5 368.149994 L 529.5 21.149994" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#003f7f"
        android:strokeColor="#003f7f"
        android:strokeWidth="5"
        android:pathData="M529.617981,20.690901c11.744995,12.0231 18.338013,28.3319
18.338013,45.3379l0,160.295204l0,0l0,96.177002l0,0c0,35.410004
-28.03302,64.11499
-62.613007,64.11499l-256.152985,0l-136.615303,0l-28.463097,0c-17.289352,0
-32.942213,-7.176239 -44.272736,-18.778748l509.779114,-347.146349z" />
</vector>
```

and layout xml file like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="{YOUR_CONTEXT}">

    <View
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/two_colored_roundrect"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

(position and dimensions of `View` - just for example) and as result you should get something like this:

[image: Two-colored round rect background]

And you can change colors of path stroke and fill, like in answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35625099/6950238) question.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and will let you know :) Once again thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I have a library to do that. 
Basicilly I draw 2 Triangles and you can specify the direction left corner to right corner or right corner to left corner.

[Library](https://github.com/massivedisaster/DiagonalDrawable)

Comment: Awesome!! I have one suggestion though, I don't know if it's already possible (haven't tried the code or viewed yet). Instead of taking colors, can I use drawables?

Answer (score 0):

So, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38012842/1827254) it's now possible to use colour resources with vector drawables.
So what you have to do is:

1. Create the shape you want with your favourite software (Illustrator for example)
2. export it as an SVG file
3. Convert it into an XML using tools like [this one](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) or Android Studio directly.

Now that you have your drawable, replace all the colours by the resources you want to use. (e.g: `android:fillColor="#0000"` become `android:fillColor="@color/custom_black"`).

Then in your `ImageView`, instead of `android:src=""` use `app:srcCompat` to set the drawable.

**Don't forget** to add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` under `defaultConfig` in your gradle file.

I've tested on both API 19 and 24, and it works.

**EDIT**: I'm using Support Library version 26.0.2

Comment: Thanks, Will try this out and will let you know. Also can you post the screenshot of the output you have received?

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot of your output?

Comment: I haven't generated the exact same output. I've tried with another drawable that I have. But it will work the same. The only thing you need to do is to create the SVG and to follow the instructions. The SVG need obviously to look exactly like the image in your post.