# VectorDrawables are not working on android prior api 21 (although compat vectors are enabled)

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

I have following in my app:

```
// Config
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

// Activity
public abstract class BaseActivity<T extends ViewDataBinding> extends AppCompatActivity {
    static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
}

// XML; Location: res/drawable
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btAdd"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/md_white_1000"/>
```

Still I get following exception on devices running android API < 21:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_add_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070070
```

This is a vector drawable. I thought above two statements will have the effect, that vector drawables are converted to pngs for devices running android API < 21.

What I do:

- enable `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary`
- call `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);`
- make sure the vector drawables are not located under `res/drawables-any` but `res/drawables`
- use `app:srcCompat` for `ImageViews` instead of `app:src` => not relevant for my issue, as I am using `android:drawableLeft`
- I use target API 26 + support library version 26.1.0

What am I still missing?

Comment: Update SupportLibraryVersion -> Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484748/appcompat-23-3-support-vectors-no-longer-work

Comment: I'm using the newest api 26 versions already... Added this info to my question

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/38012842/4895063